# Repeat a CGAffineTransformMakeRotation in Swift

Tags: swift, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I want to replace a view with a kind of fadeIn/fadeOut with rotation. 
Here is my function

```
func animateSendButton(enter: Bool)
{
    let rotation: CGFloat = enter ? 180 : -180

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        let transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(rotation))
        self.sendImage.transform = transform
        self.sendImage.layer.opacity = enter ? 0.0 : 0.87
        self.sendImage2.transform = transform
        self.sendImage2.layer.opacity = enter ? 0.87 : 0.0

    })
}
```

However the rotation works just one time and after only opacity change. 
I tried with CGATransformRotate but it didn't worked.

Is there a way to repeat it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting the transform to its identity  :)

```
func animateSendButton(enter: Bool)
{
    let alpha = enter ? 0.0 : 0.87
    let transfrom = enter ? CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(180)) : CGAffineTransformIdentity

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.sendImage.transform = transform
        self.sendImage.layer.opacity = alpha
        self.sendImage2.transform = transform
        self.sendImage2.layer.opacity = alpha

    }) { (complete) in

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. However that's not really what I want to do. My animation has to revert when I clicked on a button and here when I click the repeat option make animation revert without a second click.

Comment: I just updated my answer to reflect your comments :)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update the options, edited my answer

Comment: Ensure you fix your code accordingly, the answer that you may have used, is technically still repeating the animation, you don't see it because there is nothing to repeat, it become a loop that keeps repeating to the same value, and since it's the same you don't see what happens!!

Comment: Yep I've fix it and forgot to precise in my previous answer !

Comment: Phewww... Awesome :)